# Remove backslash and slash after file extension in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, backslash, slash

Htaccess is not my favourite and please be kind enough to help me with this.

Ex. Www.domain.com/about.php shows the site with styles rightly. In the browser if add www.domain.com/about.php/  or  www.domain.com/about.php\  all the styles are ruined and page is distorted.

How to eradicate backslash and slash after file extension in htaccess.

Appreciate your help
Rgds

Comment: Please provide your current `.htaccess` configuration.

Comment: I don't have one the server is new

Answer (score 0):

It is `path/to/style.css` but when you add `/` after `about.php` , the included file path will be changed to `about.php/path/to/style.css` so nothing will show up.

To solve this issue add this `<base href="/">` between `<head>` Tags in order to keep a base fixed :

```
 <head>
 <base href="/">
</head>
```

**Update:**

As per your comment that you want to add rules in `.htaccess` for this case , try this :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^(.+)\.php/(.*)(\.css)$      $2$3 [L]
```

Comment: @Ian did you tried it ? there is a solution by htaccess but this better and should work unless you have special structure ,  just try to open page source when you add \ after about,php and click on css file and let me know the URL

Comment: ok after requesting  public/test_folder/about.php  open page source ad click on css file then repeated with public/test_folder/about.php , let me know the URl , you could see the difference and i could be able to know what happened

Comment: Hi, after adding your code I know what you mean, http://www.example.com/css/layout.css  its referring there, but my original file is at:http://www.example.com/folder/new/about.php  

I think it would be great mohammed to have a htaccess to stop or redirect to 404.html if type in browser after a "file name" about.php/ or about.php\ "inside any folder UNDER Public html" this is secure If can please

Comment: Dear Mohammed thank you so much for the update. Your command perfectly works but this lets the images go empty. After so much of research, I found this and this works for the root thats to say the public folder only:  " RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\/$ /$1/ [R=404,L] "  this works and it redirects to the 404. that is all fine. But it dosent work on sub folders. 

RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php\/$ /$1/ [R=404,L] How can I make it work for sub folders also, that's to say this line to work on all folders please. Thank you once again. Appreciate your help.